# Select the line above a search term in text document?

Tags: regex, text, text-editor, textmate

I'm currently using this in TextMate to find a term and select the entire line in a text document:

```
^.*language.*?$
```

I would like this to also select the line above if possible.

I've tried researching this myself but haven't had much luck.

I've figured out how to include the line below using \n but I don't know how to do the line above.

Comment: Try matching `^.*\r?\n.*language.*\r?\n`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/osXfoQ/1)

Comment: @CarySwoveland That works! Thank you! And how would I go about adding more lines above the selection if needed? E.g. if I want to select 3 lines above my search term?

Comment: Actually I think I've got it.

`^.*\r?\n.*^.*\r?\n.*language.*\r?\n.*`

Comment: Yes (but your regex matches just two lines before the line containing "language"), or `(?:^.*\r?\n){3}.*language.*\r?\n`. If you want to match 0-3 lines before the *next* line containing "language", as many as possible, you could use `(?:^.*\r?\n){0,3}?.*language.*\r?\n`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ss8zLq/1).